# Is setState running again and again in this React code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created three react components and I don't know why I am getting an infinite network request and this warning: index.js:1375 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. 
    in MenuCategory (at App.js:19)
    in App (at src/​index.js:5)

also a network request in MenuItems.js is getting called in a loop. I think it is due to setState but I don't know where is the error. 
And here is my code  :

```
import React from "react";
import MenuCategory from "./components/MenuCategory";
import MenuItems from "./components/MenuItems";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { shortName: "" };
  }
  handleProps = ss => {
    if (this.state.shortName === "") {
      this.setState({ shortName: ss });
    }
    // console.log(ss, ".../PP");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MenuCategory callback={this.handleProps} />
        <MenuItems shortNameProp={this.state.shortName} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";

class MenuCategory extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { category: "", selectedCat: "" };
  }
  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    const url = "http://stream-restaurant-menu-svc.herokuapp.com/category";
    await fetch(url)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(element => {
        this.setState({ category: element });
      });
  }

  menuCat = () => {
    let cat = this.state.category;
    // console.log(cat, "...Cat", this.state.selectedCat, "...Cat");

    if (this.state.selectedCat !== "") {
      this.props.callback(this.state.selectedCat);
    }

    return cat.map(items => {
      return (
        <li
          key={items.short_name}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedCat: items.short_name })}
        >
          {items.name}
        </li>
      );
    });
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.category.length > 0 ? this.menuCat() : null}</div>;
  }
}
export default MenuCategory;
```

```
import React from "react";

class MenuItems extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { catItems: "", items: "" };
  }
  renderItems = () => {
    let shortName = this.props.shortNameProp;
    if (shortName !== "") {
      const url =
        "https://stream-restaurant-menu-svc.herokuapp.com/item?category=" +
        shortName;
      fetch(url)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(element => {
          this.setState({ items: element });
        });
    }
    if (this.state.items !== "") {
      let selectedMenu = this.state.items;
      console.log(selectedMenu);

      return selectedMenu.map(item => {
        return <div key={item.name}> {item.name}</div>;
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderItems()}</div>;
  }
}
export default MenuItems;
```

Comment: It can, if the `if` conditions around the `callback` execute / their conditions are true. Why store the same data in two places that are both local states? why not just pass the state as props to the child? this'll help eliminate bugs where their value potentially diverges

Comment: Since you're doing async stuff, just use `componentDidMount` instead of `UNSAFE_componentWillMount`. Also, in `MenuItem`, the infinite loop is cos `renderItems` calls a `setState` in the fetch callback. This will trigger a re-render, which will trigger a calling of `renderItems`, which calls `setState`, which triggers a re-render, etc. etc.. Just call fetch once on, for example, `componentDidMount` and store items in state. In render, just render a loading spinner or some loading message until `this.state.items` is defined

Answer (score 0):

Let's call `App` a parent and `MenuCategory` a child.
Let's denote a function call as the `'->'` sign.

There is an infinite loop formed like that:

`child.render -> child.menuCat -> child.props.callback -> parent.handleProps -> parent.setState -> parent.render -> child.render`.